# How to send data to specific user (web browser client) with Flask?

Tags: python-3.x, flask

I would like to send data to specific web browser client with Flask. Like Flask-SocketIO, but without to use that or any websocket else.

With Flask-SocketIO, this would be like this:

routes.py

```
@socketio.on("getting_data", namespace="/private")
def get_data(info):
  json_response = {
    "field1": "data1",
    "field2": "data2"
  }

  emit("send_data", json_response, room=request.sid)
```

index.html

```
var private_socket = io.connect(document.location.origin + '/private');

private_socket.emit('getting_data', {'key' : 'value'});

private_socket.on('send_data', function(info){
  console.log(info);
});
```

I would like to do the same but without websockets.

Comment: Without using WebSockets, the client would need to initiate the package exchange. You would need to call a JavaScript-function that polls the server using AJAX. Note that this is what `Flask-SocketIO` does if WebSockets are not supported or it is configured to do so. The client would repeatedly ask if there are any messages for this specific user. You could simply use cookies to give any user an id.

Comment: I'm trying with AJAX and Flask session. Thanks anyway.